# How do you design an MVC controller using RouteAttributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm developing a controller named **at** and ultimately it requires a **project number** and a **step number**

So http://myapp/at/5/step/6 would mean use Project = 5 and Step = 6

I wan't to handle all cases such as:

http://myapp/at (try to find the last project used in the DB)

http://myapp/at/1 (try to find the step in the DB for project 1)

Below works, but am I making this more difficult than necessary?

```
public class ATController : Controller
{
    [Route("at/{project:int}/step/{step:int}")]
    public ActionResult Index(int project, int step)
    {
        var m = new ATViewModel();
        m.Project = project;
        m.Step = step;
        return View(m);
    }

    [Route("at/{project:int}")]
    public ActionResult ProjectSuppliedNoStep(int project)
    {
        var p = project;
        var s = 33;   //fake lookup
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { project = p, step = s });
    }

    [Route("at")]
    public ActionResult NoProjectNoStep()
    {
        var p = 7;  //fake lookup
        var s = 33;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { project = p, step = s });
    }
}
```

BTW, this doesn't unit test very well. **ProjectSuppliedNoStep** and **NoProjectNoStep** always return null.  I think it's because it's calling RedirectToAction.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have multiple `Route` attributes.  Maybe you could combine this with making the parameters optional?

```
[Route("at/{project:int?}/step/{step:int?}")]
[Route("at/{project:int?}")]
[Route("at")]
public ActionResult Index(int? project, int? step)
{
    var m = new ATViewModel();

    if (project.HasValue)
    {
        m.Project = project.Value;

        if (step.HasValue)
        {
            m.Step = step.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            m.Step = 33;   //fake lookup;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        m.Project = 7;   //fake lookup;
        m.Step = 33;     //fake lookup;
    }

    return View(m);
}
```

Comment: I thought of that approach, but adding/deleting routes would in one method would violate the open/ closed principle

Answer (score 0):

You can read up on [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) to understand it better.

Referencing the above your controller will look like...

```
[RoutePrefix("at")]
public class ATController : Controller
{
    //GET /at/5/step/6
    [Route("{project:int}/step/{step:int}")]
    public ActionResult Index(int project, int step) {
        var m = new ATViewModel();
        m.Project = project;
        m.Step = step;
        return View(m);
    }

    //GET /at/1
    [Route("{project:int}")]
    public ActionResult ProjectSuppliedNoStep(int project) {
        var p = project;
        var s = 33;   //fake lookup
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { project = p, step = s });
    }

    //GET /at
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult NoProjectNoStep() {
        var p = 7;  //fake lookup
        var s = 33;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { project = p, step = s });
    }
}
```

Here are also some unit tests for your controller that all pass (GREEN) when tested.

```
[TestClass]
public class MvcControllerAttributeRouteTests : ControllerUnitTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index_Should_Return_ViewResult_With_Model() {
        //Arrange
        int project = 5;
        int step = 6;
        var controller = new ATController();
        //Act
        var actionResult = controller.Index(project, step);
        var viewResult = actionResult as ViewResult;
        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);
        Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult.Model);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(viewResult.Model, typeof(ATViewModel));
        var viewModel = viewResult.Model as ATViewModel;
        Assert.AreEqual(project, viewModel.Project);
        Assert.AreEqual(step, viewModel.Step);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Project_Supplied_No_Step_Should_Redirect_To_Index() {
        //Arrange
        int project = 1;
        var controller = new ATController();
        //Act
        var actionResult = controller.ProjectSuppliedNoStep(project);
        var result = actionResult as RedirectToRouteResult;
        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.RouteValues["action"], "the redirection was to at.index action");
        Assert.AreEqual(project, result.RouteValues["project"]);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void No_Porject_No_Step_Should_Redirect_To_Index() {
        //Arrange
        var controller = new ATController();
        //Act
        var actionResult = controller.NoProjectNoStep();
        var result = actionResult as RedirectToRouteResult;
        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.RouteValues["action"], "the redirection was to at.index action");
        CollectionAssert.Contains(result.RouteValues.Keys, "project");
        CollectionAssert.Contains(result.RouteValues.Keys, "step");
    }
}
```

Comment: Other than the RoutePrefix, how is your controller class different than mine?

Comment: You were already on the right path. There wasn't much to change other than that. You can try the other answer as well but I'm not familiar with that structure. It is convenient though if it works.

Comment: I like your approach better as it is follows open/closed principle. I think your unit tests will work.  That's a relief.

Comment: `var actionResult = controller.Index(project, step);` does not have an extension for Index.  How is this even compiling for you?

Comment: Did you mean `ProjectStep' instead of `Index`?  That does work btw.  Just wondering how it compiled.

Comment: Thats a typo on my part after i pasted it into the answer. will fix. It is suppose to be Index.